# Can I build (not run) a Windows Docker image from a Linux host?

Tags: windows, docker

I am new to Docker and container technologies in general so sorry if this is a naive question. Would it possible to just build (not run!) a Windows Docker image from a Linux machine from a Dockerfile?

Answer (score 3):

For the most part, no, it's not.

The real technical problem you'll run into is that it's almost impossible to build an image without `RUN` steps in the Dockerfile.  These do, internally, create containers and run them, and you can't run a Windows container without a Windows host.  (Where you can apparently run Linux containers on non-Linux hosts, there's either a layer like WSL or a Linux virtual machine involved.)

If you could build an image without `RUN`ning anything it might be possible via the Dockerfile [`FROM --platform=windows/amd64`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) option, but again, you'd be very limited in what you could actually do.

I could imagine wanting this in a couple of specific scenarios.  You'd have to do all of the setup in a platform-independent way outside the container.  A Java application, for example, can be fully compiled to a portable `.jar` file and then `COPY`ed into the final image without `RUN`ning anything.  I can also imagine a setup building a cross-compiler in an earlier Dockerfile stage (and this is often a pretty hairy exercise) and then `COPY`ing a cross-compiled binary into a Windows image.  It might be easier to just run Linux images on Windows via WSL, though.