# Is virtualization capability a requirement for a windows machine to build a windows docker image?

Tags: docker, github-actions, docker-for-windows, docker-build, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

## Questions

1. Do you need virtualization to run docker build for a windows docker image?  If so can you please share the docs?
2. Does the Github hosted windows runner support virtualization?  Or does it just have docker installed?

Any references to documentation would be much appreciated :)

## Context

- I would like use a github action to build a windows image and push it to ecr
- I have successfully been able to do this using the Github hosted windows runner
- I would like to create a self hosted Github Runner for this action
- I know hyper v or some sort of virtualization capability is required for **running** a windows docker container, but I cannot find information on whether or not that is required for **building** a windows container
- info: it seems that at one point the windows github runner did not support any container actions but the runner now has docker installed: https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/904
- I am trying to determine what I need to provision for my self hosted windows github runner to be able to build a windows docker image.

Comment: The switch seems to be in the agent code base, so I don’t think your attempt on the hardware side helps.

Comment: I am confused by what you mean here-- could you please elaborate?  I think maybe you are getting at virtualization features I mentioned?  I know that you need virtualization features enabled on windows to run docker images but I am unsure and have been unable to find docs on whether I need those features to build a windows image.  Do you know if that is a requirement for building docker images?

Comment: I meant that "Error: Container operations are only supported on Linux runners" seems to be a hard coded error as Windows container was not even considered a supported scenario. If you cannot even unlock that, moving forward on other parts like virtualization enabled hardware can be pointless. "jelmansouri-legion" reported some success but no much detail is there for you to follow.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure if we are on the same page here.. So for context I was able to use a github hosted windows runner to build a windows docker container and then push that image to ecr.  I want to do this in a self hosted runner, and I am trying to figure out what the system requirements for the runner need to be in order to build a docker windows container.  I am aware that to run docker windows docker containers, the system needs virtualization features enabled.  I am trying to determine if that is also a requirement for just building an image.

Comment: A small update: I found a somewhat related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71910574/can-i-build-not-run-a-windows-docker-image-from-a-linux-host that indicates to me that the build process actually spins up and runs window containers, so maybe for this reasoning docker build for windows containers would have the same virtualization system requirements as docker run?